# В некоторых сниппетах отсутствуют кнопки для запуска

Tags: дефект, поддержка, статус-так-задумано, сниппеты

[В двух ответах из трёх](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/597561/178988) (в обоих кроме удалённого) не отображаются кнопки <kbd>Выполнить код</kbd>, <kbd>Копировать код в ответ</kbd> и <kbd>Развернуть фрагмент</kbd>. Могу предположить, что это связано с рейтингом -3, но это же нелогично - почему должно быть нельзя запускать сниппет из заминусованного ответа?

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: а у меня не воспроизводится

Comment: @Grundy, у меня уже тоже. Либо дело в рейтинге - там уже плюсов наставили, либо Николас что-то сделал - в одном из сообщений есть его правка и роллбэк.

Comment: может быть просто не правильно вставлен код и поэтому не работает воспроизведение?

Comment: @Insider, правильно. Раньше же работало. И сейчас заработало.

Answer (score 4):

Так задумано. Сниппеты перестают работать при рейтинге сообщения -3 и ниже (в оригинале less than, возможно порог поменяли):

[Introducing Runnable JavaScript, CSS, and HTML Code Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

> Like all other aspects of our site, Stack Snippets are ultimately **governed by the community**. Because users can still write code that creates annoying behaviors like infinite loops or pop-ups, we disable snippets on any post that is heavily downvoted (scoring less than -3 on Stack Overflow, -8 on Meta). If you see bad code that you think should be disabled, **downvote the post**.

Comment: Это вроде вполне правкой решается? Зачем запрещать-то?

Comment: @Qwertiy честно, не знаю

Comment: @Qwertiy что именно решается правкой?

Comment: @alexolut, если сниппет чем-то вредит, поэтому не стоит его запускать, то следует не минусовать ответ, а исправить. Как крайний вариант - удалить метку сниппета, чтобы он стал просто кодом. Как более нормальный, например, заменить alert на console.log. А если уж там совсем трояна пытаются в сниппет упихать, то тревога - спам. Как-то так. Не вижу причин, почему надо именно -3, чтобы не запускать сниппеты. Я вполне могу хотеть посмотреть, что же конкретно не так с кодом в ответе, а меня этой возможности просто так лишают. Нехорошо.

Comment: @Qwertiy я думаю, причина в том, что "исправить" и "минусануть" это действия, требующие немного разных мозговых усилий и более того, знаний вообще. Может быть для продвинутых типа Вас можно было бы и сделать опцию вида "я понимаю риск" в настройках профиля и не отключать кнопку для заминусованных ответов. Но для рядовых участников упомянутая защита не помещает наверное. Зависит от степени возможных деструктивных действий. Например, трое нажали - получили форматирование диска, после этого нажали "минус" :) и чётвёртый уже обезопашен.

Comment: @alexolut, вообще-то сниппеты в браузерной песочнице - что-то вредоносное из них сделать сложно. В худшем случае заблокировать браузер алертами (кстати, насколько я помню, это можно в параметрах ifram'а задать).

Comment: @Qwertiy если Вам кажется, что такая блокировка - это черезчур, то попробуйте оформить [meta-tag:feature-request] с обоснованиями на [Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/). Может прольются на свет какие-то новые детали, или Вы действительно добьётесь своего.